# Failed to load native dll (C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Temp\...\dbdata.dll

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string, sqlanywhere, sap-iq

I'm trying to create an SAConnection into a Sybase IQ database. I'm attempting to create the connection through a simple visual studio C# application.

My code fails at:

```
SAConnection connection = new SAConnection(connString);
```

And pops up with a message box:

SQL Anywhere ADO.NET DataProvider

```
Failed to load native dll (C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Temp\{16AA8FB8-4A98-4757-B7A5-0FF22C0A6E33}_0\dbdata.dll
```

[Link to picture of messagebox](http://i43.tinypic.com/5uenoy.png)

The code subsequently throws an exception:

```
"The type initializer for 'iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection' threw an exception" with InnerException as described in the message box.
```

I've checked and double checked the connection string and am confident it is correct. I am using iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere version 11.0.0.11292 and am connecting to a Sybase IQ 
database. I am running Win7 64 bit and can connect to the database without a problem in Aqua Data Studio.  Any ideas on this would be great.

Comment: Why is it loading the dll from such an obscure location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling Sybase IQ drivers and updating to latest version of iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.